# How to compile stage on Mac OS X Lion?

Tags: simulation, stage, macos, macos-lion, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I'm trying to compile stage on my OS X but I'm getting an error with libjpeg:

$ rosmake stage --rosdep-install
Using environment variable ROS_OS_OVERRIDE name = osxbrew version = lion
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['stage']
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory/Users/user/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120316-145058
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['stage'] to:
['stage']
[ rosmake ] Generating Install Script using rosdep then executing. This may take a minute, you will be prompted for permissions. . .
Using environment variable ROS_OS_OVERRIDE name = osxbrew version = lion
Failed to find rosdep libjpeg for package stage on OS:osxbrew version:lion
[ rosmake ] rosdep install failed: Rosdep install failed

Also:

$ brew install libjpeg
Warning: jpeg already installed

I followed the Homebrew Mac OS X install tutorial here:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/electric/Installation/OSX/Homebrew

My version of OS X is 10.7.3

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29875/how-to-compile-stage-on-mac-os-x-lion?/) by [Gonçalo Cabrita](https://answers.ros.org/users/83/gon%C3%A7alo-cabrita/) on ROS Answers with karma: 591 on 2012-03-16

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2012-03-16**:
Stage 3 or Stage 4?

**Comment by [Gonçalo Cabrita](https://answers.ros.org/users/83/gon%C3%A7alo-cabrita/) on 2012-03-16**:
Stage 3.2.2, its what comes with electric, forgot to mention that!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Unfortunately Stage 3.2.2 does not work on OS X.  Stage 4.x does however, and there are patches for stage_ros to be compatible for Stage 4 as well.  I would recommend that as a solution.

Here are some general notes about it on my blog:

http://williamjwoodall.com/2011/09/23/ros-and-stage4-on-os-x/

---

Originally posted by [WilliamWoodall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3078/williamwoodall/) with karma: 1626 on 2012-08-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2